# Is it possible to run a post build event when the whole compilation finishes in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, fxcop, post-build-event, build-events

I have a solution with multiple projects and we use FxCop. We want to run it once the compilation requested finishes (it may be one project, a folder with several folders or the whole solution).

Is there a way of doing this? We currently do it per project but this has some drawbacks.

Comment: Yes, see this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn376353.aspx

Comment: Consider to use Teamcity for this. It's overhead to run it every time on developer machines. Also look here: http://sedodream.com/2010/10/22/MSBuildExtendingTheSolutionBuild.aspx

Comment: @AuthorProxy: it is probably worse to have to request a build just to be able to fix the tons of fxcop issues you will find and repeat it after each iteration fix. We already have a build definition that disables the fxcop in case you are not interested in it.

Comment: We use stylecop and run it manually before publish to teamcity, because most time we know when we need to retest and when we not need this. For example while changing javascript or configs, we don't whant to wait while stylecop retest clean solution. TC makes final check. And everything is ok. Furthemore you can attach it to git precommit event handler.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a way to do it by putting a file next to your solution file [with a specific naming pattern](http://sedodream.com/2010/10/22/MSBuildExtendingTheSolutionBuild.aspx): `after.{Your solution name here}.sln.targets`

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?-->
<project toolsversion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <target name="AtTheStart" beforetargets="Build">
    <message text="GenerateCode target running" importance="high">
    </message>
  </target>
  <target name="AtTheEnd" aftertargets="Build">
    <message text="GenerateCode target running" importance="high">
    </message>
  </target>
</project>
```

But if you want to run FxCop effectively and have visualstudio installed, you can actually activate it during the build by including `/p:RunCodeAnalysis=true` or `/p:RunCodeAnalysis=always` on the call to MsBuild. This will run the configured ruleset file during the build. `/p:CodeAnalysisRuleSet=PathTo.ruleset` will let you specify a specific ruleset file.

The commandline will always overwrite the project's own configuration. And it will run in the most optimal way.

Comment: The targets file seems very promising. We already have custom rules for FxCop 10 so we prefer to not port them to VS2013.

Comment: CodeAnalysis will happily run your custom rules as well when you register them using a `.ruleset` file. They need to be recompiled against the matching visual studio version to run though.

Comment: `/p:RunCodeAnalysis=true`

Answer (score 1):

I would put the FxCop project set (with all the dll's in all your projects) and call it after all the projects are built in VS.